# Uses of "Cyclic" vs. "Cyclical"?

Tags: semantics, ic-ical

As an engineering undergrad, I refer to "cyclic motion". My friend, an arts student, uses the term "cyclical unemployment" (whatever that means) instead.

The only article I can find on the web about this didn't reach any conclusion except that words with -ic and -ical endings were normally the same, but occasionally the language has evolved to use them in different contexts (for example most people would see a difference between "magic" and "magical") [[contrapunctus.net]](http://contrapunctus.net/blog/2007/suffixation).

Is this divide entirely just convention in respective subjects?

Comment: Both are acceptable as adjectives, but I would much prefer cyclical in both instances you quote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks! [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical/6600#6600) seems to give a good answer.

Comment: Generally x-ic is a subset of x-ical : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171509/geometric-or-geometrical/171654#171654

Comment: For this particular word, the use cases should often be regarded as technical language, and the conventions of the subject followed. In mathematics, anyone talking about "cyclical groups" rather than "cyclic groups" would receive funny looks; and it would be peculiar to use either term to describe a function, for which the correct adjective is *periodic*.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah - although the actual question I cited was closed, I figured one of the duplinks within that would probably cover the general case well enough. I didn't check them all out myself, but if the *first* one worked for you that's good.

Comment: This is the first actual useful deployment of a tag I have seen. Well done, @RegDwigнt.